# Using Appium Grid when UDID of Android devices are the same

Tags: java, android, appium, selenium-grid

I am currently using Appium to automate the configuration of Android devices at my job. I would like to set up a Grid so I may configure multiple devices at once, but I am wondering how I should go about this if all my devices share the same UDID.

After connecting two of my tablets and use an `adb devices` command, I am given a prompt that tells me my device names, both "0123456789ABCDEF". This is the case with every tablet my company uses.

As far as I know, my Appium test script will have to programmatically pass the UDIDs of each device to each node, so they run the possibility of getting caught up.

Is there any other "udid" value that I could use to discern between different tablets? How would I programmatically extract that value?

Comment: Oh! I always thought that the UDID was unique.

Comment: @nullpointer I guess not :(

Answer (score 0):

Device UDID is never the same unless you are running emulators (AVD or Genymotion). If that is the case there are couple of work arounds where you can change the emulators UDID. One being launching AVD android emulator from command line where you can give UDID of your choice. Hope this helps.